# scss error - &:not(": expected ")", was "'.full')

Tags: css, sass

I'm a bit confused with the following errors. I have no experience with SCSS.. it's a file a subcontracting front-end designer company gave us.
I am attempting to compile using KOALA that seemed to be an easy open source free windows sass compiler.

Errors:

```
assets\sass\main.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "&:not(": expected ")", was "'.full')"
        on line 23 of assets/sass/components/_last-update.scss
        from line 13 of assets/sass/_components.scss
        from line 8 of assets\sass\main.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

The specific code causing the error seems to be:

```
@media (min-width: $bp-medium) {
        &:not('.full') { max-width: 60%; }
        margin-bottom: $vertical-spacing-medium;
    }
```

Specifically:

> &:not('.full') { max-width: 60%; }

I tried removing that part all together and it seems to work but I havn't understood yet the SCSS/SASS syntax and why it would not be working. I've only been explosed to this language for 30' now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem are the hypens in the selector. e.g.

```
&:not('.full') { max-width: 60%; }
```

should become

```
&:not(.full) { max-width: 60%; }
```

as defined by the specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Is it possible to use `-` in the selection? I.e. 
`&:not(hello-world)`

Comment: i think it is :)